# Xamarin iOS: Source file is not valid UTF-8

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to compile and deploy an iOS app on VS 2019 (v16.10.3) for Windows, but I keep getting all kinds of weird issues. This started happening recently.

[image]

How does one resolve "source file is not valid UTF-8" errors?

Comment: have you checked any of the files to verify that they are UTF-8?

Comment: Which files specifically? Are you saying I should go through every single file in the project?

Comment: Btw, I created a brand new Xamarin Forms solution. It's got the same problem. I'm unable to compile.

Comment: If you have the same error on many files, checking one of the to see if it is a false positive or not seems like a good first step